# Solving $\sqrt{x+5} = x - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently learning about radicals and simplifying them, and I came across this problem on the internet and tried to solve it:

$$\sqrt{x+5} = x - 1$$

So I used this logic:

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x+5} &= x - 1 \\
x + 5 &= (x-1)^2 \\
x + 5 &= (x-1)(x-1) \\
x + 5 &= x^2 - 2x + 1 \\
0 &= x^2 - 3x - 4 \\
0 &= (x-4)(x+1) \\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $x = -1$ and $x = 4$ satisfy the equation $0 = (x-4)(x+1)$.

But then I tried to plug them in the original problem $\sqrt{x+5}=x-1$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4 + 5} &= 4 - 1 \\
\sqrt{9} &= 3 \\
3 &= 3
\end{align}
$$

So using 4 works as expected, but when using $-1$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{-1 + 5} &= -1 - 1 \\
\sqrt{4} &= -2 \\
2 &\ne -2
\end{align}
$$

**At what stage am I going wrong?**

And according the [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2b5%29%5E%281/2%29%20=%20x%20-%201), the solution is $x = 4$.

Comment: Hah, just realized I could have inputted the LaTeX directly in the post instead of fiddling around with the CodeCogs Equation Editor.

Comment: I'm impressed by your effort to show your work, and with such care! Yes, being able to use LaTeX on this site is a really nice feature.

Comment: Also: just to chime in with user9716, there was/is nothing wrong with the *procedure* you used for solving the given equation.  The thing to remember is that when you then solve for a variable, you arrive at *potential* solutions: if there is/are a solution, it will be among the potential solutions.  So it was smart for you to have checked both values; that's the only way to confirm or discard potential solutions.

Comment: This is a *classic* example of how we lie to students when we first teach them algebra. When you perform a sequence of algebraic manipulations on an equation to solve for $x$, you are really showing an implication: $\sqrt{x+5}=x-1$ implies that $x=-1$ or $x=4$. However we haven't shown the reverse implication: $x=-1$ or $x=4$ implies $\sqrt{x+5}=x-1$, and in fact this reverse implication is false because squaring both sides is not a reversible step.

Comment: Like amWhy. $ $

Comment: Solve the equation: $x=1$. Step 1) Square both sides: $x^2 = 1$. Step 2) Roots are $+1$ and $-1$...

Comment: Kevin Reid, thanks for taking the time to convert my images into LaTeX.  I was actually planning to do it but I guess the community was ahead of me :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At no stage...

Here is what happens, you squared the equation

$$\sqrt{x+5} =x-1 \,.$$

But then, if the two sides of the equation have the same absolute value, but opposite signs they are not equal in this equation but they become equal at the next step.

This means that the equation $x+5=(x-1)^2$ possibly has more solutions. So the answers you got at the end are no necessarily the solution, they are just the **possible solutions**.

You have to check which one works.

+1 for showing your work :)

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's what I was confused about before, because I thought they where **solutions**, not *potential* solutions.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is:
$$x+5 = (x - 1)^2$$
doesn't imply
$$\sqrt{x + 5} = x - 1$$
but
$$\sqrt{x + 5} = \vert x - 1\vert$$

Comment: But what is the reason it implies the absolute value?

Comment: Roots return always positive numbers, so $\sqrt{a^2}$ is $a$ if $a\ge 0$, $-a$ otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that when you square both sides of an equation you may introduce new roots. The new equation has all the solutions of the original one, but may have some that are not.

From $A^{2}-B^{2}=\left( A-B\right) (A+B)$ you can say that $A-B=0\Rightarrow A^{2}-B^{2}=0$ and $A+B=0\Rightarrow A^{2}-B^{2}=0$. But while $A=B$ is a solution of $A-B=0$, $A=-B$ is not, unless $A=B=0$. In the question $A=\sqrt{x+5}$, $B=x-1$.

As I wrote [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40077/trig-equation-help-please/40084#40084), in general the equation $A^n=B^n$ has all the solutions of the equation $A=B$ but may have additional ones. This is a consequence of the algebraic identity

$$A^n-B^n=(A-B)(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+\cdots +AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1}).$$

Comment: I have been confused about this 'possible solutions' thing for some time, but reading your answer made it clearer. So, is what you explained here *All* there is to it (as in, this explains covers all cases when we have that A $\implies$B and we get, say, $x$ & $y$ as the solutions, they may or may not be solutions of the original equation,(i.e. A)?) If it does not, do you know where I can read up on it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Work backwards. Starting with $x=-1$ and $x=4$, when you work backwards through your steps and rewrite everything to get to the very beginning, you end by taking a square-root. When you take that square-root, you have two possible solutions: $+\sqrt{x+5}$ and $-\sqrt{x+5}\quad$. $x=-1$ solves one, $x=4$ solves the other.

Answer (score 2):

Plugging $x= -1$ into each step of your work, you get :
$$\begin{align}2 = -2 \\ 4 = 4 \\ 4 = 4 \\ 4 = 4 \\ 0 = 0 \\ 0 = 0 \end{align}$$
Thus without any thinking, you know that the error is in the first step, because $2^2 = 4 = 4 = (-2)^2$, but $2 \neq -2$

Comment: There is no *error*.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.
Why do you have 3 lines showing `4 = 4` and two lines showing `0 = 0`?

Comment: He went line by line in your question under "So I used this logic" and substituted $-1$ for $x$ in each line, then evaluated each side of the equation.  So the last $4=4$ comes from  $x+5=x^2-2x+1$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x+5} = x - 1$
Because, you need to put condition $x\geq 1$
So, If you tried to plug $x = -1 < 1$, which not satified.

Answer (score 1):

1. Function *on the left hand side* is strictly increasing (i.e always increasing).
2. Function *on the right hand side* is strictly increasing (i.e always increasing) too.
3. We draw a graph to find out where too look for the roots. You [can use this](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/) or any other tool to draw two graphs for left and right hand side functions. We'll see that there is one interception at $x=4$ and there will be no other interceptions because functions striclty increase.